# convert a local html webpage to mhtml

Tags: python, wget

I have a html webpage stored locally (html file + folder with css/js files)

- `mypage.html`
- `mypage_files` (folder containing `css`, images, data, and `js`)

Opening mypage by clicking on it with a navigator works fine but how can I use `wget` in `python` to open and convert the local webpage to the `mhtml` format?

The idea is to obtain a single file and be able to share it by email without having to send the zipped data/css/js files as well.

Thanks!

Comment: this question does not contain two questions into one. I simply ask how to convert html to mhtml. thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be Wget in Python? Wget does not support writing singular mhtml pages. The closest you can get is having Wget output a WARC file.